# Collapse amp-accordion with close button within accordiandiv

Tags: amp-html

I have an AMP-HTML page where the user can expand an amp-accordion but the list is quite long.  To close the accordion the user must scroll way up to the top title to close.  I am hoping to add a close button at the bottom of the list that will collapse the accordion.  I can't use Jquery or inline javascript because it is AMP valid.  Here is what I have tried.  I know you can do this on a normal div, just having trouble getting it to work within an accordion. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<amp-accordion class="accordion">
<section id="topranked">
    <h4 class="bg-rust-light">Top places in Boise<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h4>
    <div class="accordiondiv" id="toprankedhide">
        <p class="half-bottom center big-text"><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x color-ship-dark"></i><br>
        Based on <strong>32,000 reviews</strong> from our guests</p>
            <a class="button bg-gray-light border-gray-dark button100 big-text" href="/official.asp?ID=1">Company1</a><br><a class="button bg-gray-light border-gray-dark button100 big-text" href="/official.asp?ID=1">Company2</a><br>
<a class="button bg-gray-light border-gray-dark button100 big-text" href="/official.asp?ID=1">Company3</a>
            <button on="tap:toprankedhide.hide">Close</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </amp-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this [feature](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-by-example/issues/183) is what you're looking for.

```
<amp-accordion>
  <section>
    <h4><span class="show-more">Show more</span> <span class="show-less">Show less</span></h4>
    <p>Id lacus amet. Aliquam eos nunc ut scelerisque lacinia, eu rutrum id, vestibulum aliqua vivamus luctus eu rhoncus ut, sodales id. Velit lacus, fermentum neque et sagittis, ac venenatis volutpat, dolore neque feugiat proin fermentum odio, odio arcu in eu wisi. </p>
  </section>
</amp-accordion>
```

You can add more text to the expanded accordion to demonstrate the longer, complete text that necessitates a "Show more"/"Show less" mechanic.

Additional references:

- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/5734
- https://github.com/ampproject/amp-by-example/issues/182

Comment: Thanks abielita, I found the same info online before I asked.  It doesn't solve my problem though.  Unless I am missing something.  I need the close button to be at the bottom of the <p>, in the text, not in the initial H4.  I tried putting <span class="show-less">Show less</span> after the text and doesn't work.  I am pretty sure it has something to do with the H4 section looking for a child. I somehow need it to look at the parent to collapse.  Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: It does not work
Tried this

<amp-accordion class="sample" expand-single-section>
  ~foreach from=$v key=kk item=vv name=xyz`
  <section class="card">
    <h4 class="card-header">~$vv`
      <span class="show-more"><i class="material-icons">expand_more</i></span>
      <span class="show-less"><i class="material-icons">expand_less</i></span>
    </h4>
    <div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <span>~$vv` hi</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  ~/foreach`
</amp-accordion>

Answer (score 0):

```
    <amp-accordion class="accordion" id="myAccordion" animate expand-single-section disable-session-states>
<section id="topranked" on="expand:topranked.scrollTo(duration=300, position='center')">
    <h4 class="bg-rust-light">Top places in Boise<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h4>
    <div class="accordiondiv" id="toprankedhide">
        <p class="half-bottom center big-text"><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x color-ship-dark"></i><br>
        Based on <strong>32,000 reviews</strong> from our guests</p>
            <a class="button bg-gray-light border-gray-dark button100 big-text" href="/official.asp?ID=1">Company1</a><br><a class="button bg-gray-light border-gray-dark button100 big-text" href="/official.asp?ID=1">Company2</a><br>
<a class="button bg-gray-light border-gray-dark button100 big-text" href="/official.asp?ID=1">Company3</a>
            <button on="tap:toprankedhide.hide">Close</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </amp-accordion>
```

Here what I did with scroll. Maybe it will help somebody in future :)
It will scroll user to the active section after section is expanded.